# How to fix UIButton's image size?

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIButton` that has an image instead of button text. But when I compile and run the project on simulator, the button size changes. I've added width and height constraints but it didn't make sense. You can see the problem in screenshots.[image: Simulator] [image: Xcode]

Storyboard Screenshot:
[image: Storyboard Screenshot]

Comment: Try tu put a background color to your UIButton and see if the image is not out of bounds of the button

Comment: I've edited the question. The problem based on `UIButton`.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of your storyboard?

Comment: edited.... @CalebKleveter

Comment: As you can see there are missing constraints or conflicts between them. Click on the "red arrow" on the top right of your view hierarchy and see what is wrong!

Comment: Please show what constraints you have added. From what I can see your constraints are conflicting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting all the constraints, then add them one by one and  test in between.